# React native accessibilityState expanded is getting read out by Android's VoiceView but not iOS' VoiceOver

Tags: ios, react-native, accessibility, jsx

In a React Native accordian component, I am trying to surface the `expanded/closed` state of each Accordian option for users that are on assistive devices e.g. Android's VoiceView, iOS' VoiceOver.

The following is working on my Android Amazon Fire but not my iPhone 11:

```js
const renderHeader = (section, _, isActive) => {
    // section.title = "How can my health coach help me?"
    return (
        <View
          accessibilityLabel={section.title}
          accessibilityState={{ expanded: isActive }} // This is only read out on Android.
          accessibilityRole="button" // Also, this is only read out on Android.
        >
          <View>
            <Text title={section.title} />
          </View>
          <Icon
            name={isActive ? "chevron-up" : "chevron-down"}
          />
        </View>
    );
```

My Amazon Fire's VoiceView reads out:

*"How can my health coach help me? Collapsed. Button. Double tap to activate."* (when the accordian is in the collapsed state)

So accessibilityState is working for Android :)

My iOS' VoiceView just reads out:

*"How can my health coach help me?"*

This is not what I want as it does not communicate the fact that the option is a button and can be collapsed/expanded i.e. accessibilityState is not working for iOS

My Accessibility Inspector (iOS) does not see the accessibilityState or accessibilityRole:

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7DXv.png)

How can I get my iOS' VoiceView to read out the expanded/closed state and also communicate the fact that the accordian option is a button i.e. it is pressable.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

XCode's Accessibility Inspector is known to provide an insufficient a11y testing environment for developers. That said, if you test the same code on an actual iPhone with VoiceOver you will find that the accessibility states are announced as expected.